# Programmatically close the start screen in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, automated-tests

We have automated UI tests that verify our software by running regularly on of virtual machines.
I'd like to add some windows 8 release preview machines to this pool, so we can run our automated test scripts against it and be sure that our app continues to work.

We ensure our tests always start with a clean slate by booting up virtual machines from a clean snapshot. When the machines boot, they have a shortcut in their start menu/startup folder which launches the scripts.

The problem is, on windows 8, the start screen is shown when the machine boots, and our UI tests can't interact with the application because the start screen blocks everything. They try to click the mouse and end up launching random metro apps by accident and all the tests fail.

I previously had this working under the windows 8 consumer preview. Our scripts call [IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when starting up, and this would cause the start screen to hide.

Under the release preview, this no longer works.

I've also tried:

- creating a shortcut to explorer.exe, [as per this article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bypass-windows-8-start-screen-to-jump-directly-to-desktop-on-startup/). It doesn't work.
- creating a shortcut to a screensaver which calls explorer/ToggleDesktop as per [this Howtogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/108349/how-to-boot-to-the-desktop-skip-metro-in-windows-8/). It doesn't work (looks like it is probably just calling through to IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're already using your VM host's API to do things like start and stop virtual machines from a script. Can you use that same API to send the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> key combination to the VM? That would show the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing in the RTM version was this:

The bootstrapper script runs, and it assumes the start menu will take over the full screen. We then use the win32 SendInput to type D E S K T O P and Return

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problems in our corporation, and we've *just* found a solution. We've taken AutoIt and made a script which clicks on the "Desktop" tile. We've then 'compiled' the AutoIt to an executable exe which we bundle with our virtual images in their respective startup folders.

[Autoit Compiler](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm%20AutoIt%20Compiler)

Our script uses the command:

```
MouseClick("left", x, y)
```

Where x and y are coordinates that are within the Desktop tile. Our images always revert to a clean slate (like yours) so this tile is always in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, compiled of bits from everywhere.

The idea is that we want to type 'desktop' followed by Enter/Return hit (Orion's idea) and do that on each log on (scheduled tasks idea from the referenced article), but avoid using a custom win32 binary. 
My solution is to use PowerShell to avoid win32 binary.

Save the following PS script in c:\sendkeys.ps1:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("desktop{ENTER}")
```

Then create a scheduled task run on each log on which starts Powershell with the following parameters:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -nologo -file c:\sendkeys.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Michael Bisbjerg

Hi! You can also use this code which press and release Windows key and send you directly to the Desktop:

```
Send("{LWINDOWN}{LWINUP}")
```

Jonathan

Comment: Is this answer meant to be a comment to another answer?